# vaadin 24 - style scroll bars for vaadin grid

Tags: css, vaadin

I'm using vaadin 24.1 and I'm trying to migrate some legacy code which uses CssImport to the new vaadin recommended method.

The original cssimport was:

```
@CssImport(value = "./themes/OnePub/components/grid.css", themeFor = "vaadin-grid")
```

I've now removed the CssImport and renamed grid.css to vaadin-grid.css.

The vaadin-grid.css file is NOT imported from the styles.css file as per my understanding of the vaadin requirments.

Within the vaadin-grid.css file I have:

```
:host([theme~="custom-grid"]) #table::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb,
{
  background: var(--op-color-purple-dark); 
}
```

The html for the grid shows:

```
<vaadin-grid multi-sort-priority="prepend" theme="custom-grid" style="...">
```

The problem is that the style is no longer being applied to the grid when it worked happily in vaadin 24 before I changed the import.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
I've also tried experimenting with the 'part' selectors

By placing the following snippet in my styles.css I can affect the grids cell:

```css
vaadin-grid[theme="custom-grid"]::part(cell)  {
   color: red;
   background-color: red;
   width: 10px;
   height: 10px;
}
```

However there doesn't appear to be any 'part' selector for the scroll bars.

Edit 2:
In response to @cfrick's question:

I hear you, but I'm not just trying to style the scrollbar. My path to vaadin-grid.css looks correct:

```
frontend/themes/OnePub/components/vaadin-grid.css.
```

I simply deleted the @cssimport, renamed grid.css to vaadin-grid.css and moved it to the above path.
Now none of the selectors work.
Here is another example:

```css
[part~="header-cell"] { 
    background-color: var(--op-color-purple-dark); 
}
```

My feeling is that vaadin is failing to find the vaadin-grid.css file.
I've tried with an import in styles.css and without one (neither work):

styles.css

```css
@import url('./components/vaadin-grid.css');
```

For clarity my code/css is all in a single project.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to reach that element through normal CSS. It doesn't have a part name because it's not intended to be styled.

In general, styling scrollbars is not something I would recommend, since it's difficult if not impossible to achieve the exact same look across different browsers and operating systems, it can confuse users who expect scrollbars to look the same across the system, and I've seen it cause weirdness on platforms where scrollbars are not visible by default.

You can still use the pre-V24 way of injecting CSS into the Grid's shadow DOM in V24. The documentation for how to do shadow DOM css is described here: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/styling/advanced/shadow-dom-styling

In case shadow DOM CSS injection isn't working for you, that's probably caused by the new pre-compiled bundle in V24 (whose purpose is to reduce the start-up time).

So you probably need to disable that bundle and restart the app to get that CSS loaded into the component: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/configuration/development-mode#disable-precompiled-bundle

You don't need to add @imports to the stylesheets in the components folder. As the docs say:

> Don’t add imports for Shadow DOM stylesheets. Shadow DOM stylesheets
> placed in the components folder are loaded automatically into
> components with matching names. You shouldn’t add @import statements
> for them in styles.css or @CssImport annotations in your Java code.

Comment: I hear you but I'm not just trying to style the scrollbar.  My path to vaadin-grid.css looks correct `frontend/themes/OnePub/components/vaadin-grid.css`. I simply deleted the @cssimport, renamed grid.css to vaadin-grid.css and moved it to the correct path and now none of the selectors work. here is another: [part~="header-cell"]  {
  background-color: var(--op-color-purple-dark); 
}. My feeling is that vaadin is failing to find the vaadin-grid.css file.

Comment: @BrettSutton Could you please turn that comment into an edit of the
question (append, don't replace) - it's easier to follow and you can
format etc. Is your theme in the same project or do you pull it from
a module/library/...?

Comment: when I add a css to the components directory - like vaadin-grid.css, does it need to be imported from the styles.css? I've tried both ways but I'm not clear from the doco if the import is required.

Comment: If it's in the proper location of the theme, the import is _not_ required. The "compiler" will pick it up and do the "theme for" for you.

Comment: @cfrick I've updated the question

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the answer accordingly.